# Snowflake SQL apply function once per partition

Tags: sql, database, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In Snowflake, we can perform a window function like this:

```
array_agg(a) over (partition by b) as c
```

Since my partitions are large (big data), and my `f` is expensive, I need to make `f(c)` evaluate only once per partition. I've attempted:

```
f(array_agg(a)) over (partition by b) as c
```

but Snowflake says this doesn't work because `f` is not a window function.

I've also attempted

```
f(array_agg(a) over (partition by b))
```

but this `f` seems to evaluate on every row. How do I make `f` calculate only once per partition, then assign the result to the entire partition?

EDIT: By far the fastest method I've tried so far is this

```
with cte as 
(
    select 
        b,
        array_agg(a) arr_a,
        f(arr_a) c
    from 
        tbl
    group by 
        b
)
select
    x.a, x.b, y.c
from 
    tbl x
left join 
    cte y on x.b = y.b
```

Taking `f` to be the array_to_string function, here's a minimal working example of the currently implemented method:

```
with tbl as (
    select
        value[0]::VARCHAR a,
        value[1]::NUMBER b
    from (
        select array_construct(array_construct('a',1),array_construct('a',2),array_construct('a',3),array_construct('b',1),array_construct('b',3),array_construct('b',4)) arr
    ), lateral flatten(arr)
),
cte as (
  select 
    b,
    array_agg(a) arr_a,
    ARRAY_TO_STRING(arr_a,'_') c
  from tbl
  group by b
)
select
  x.a, x.b, y.c
from tbl x
left join cte y
on x.b = y.b
;
```

But the join feels unnecessary. Is there a better way?

Here's a minimal reproducible example of the method I want to work:

```
with tbl as (
    select
        value[0]::VARCHAR a,
        value[1]::NUMBER b
    from (
        select array_construct(array_construct('a',1),array_construct('a',2),array_construct('a',3),array_construct('b',1),array_construct('b',3),array_construct('b',4)) arr
    ), lateral flatten(arr)
)
select
  a,
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(array_agg(a) over (partition by b),'_') as c
from tbl x
;
```

Unfortunately, in this method `f` is evaluated for each row (6 times). But ideally it would only be calculated once per b-value group (4 times)

Comment: Please edit your question to add a [mre] with dummy source data and the desired results for that dummy data.  [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Also, look into `lateral flatten` to recover the `a` values from the array (instead of a self join).

Comment: I'm working on getting a minimal working example, but per your second point, I've got a large amount of columns, some that have very large data strings and they exceed the maximum array size when collapsed into an array, so aggregating other columns, then flattening them, won't work. Though, I would be able to do it with just this column (a in the example), I would lose the other columns not discussed in this question

Comment: (this is why [mre] are necessary) Looks like a self join is your only option.

Comment: I'm wondering if caching could work - is the "expensive" f() a UDF in Python or so, perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your MVP CTE could be written as:

```
with data(a) as (
    select parse_json($1)
    from values
        ('[["a",1],["a",2],["a",3],["b",1],["b",3],["b",4]]')
), tbl as (
    select
        value[0]::VARCHAR a,
        value[1]::NUMBER b
    from data as arr
    ,lateral flatten(arr.a)
)
```

could also be written:

```
with tbl(a,b) as (
    select * from values
        ('a', 1),
        ('a', 2),
        ('a', 3),
        ('b', 1),
        ('b', 3),
        ('b', 4)      
)
```

which feels more explicit to a input state:

So now we can look at your fastest method:

```
with tbl(a,b) as (
    select * from values
        ('a', 1),
        ('a', 2),
        ('a', 3),
        ('b', 1),
        ('b', 3),
        ('b', 4)      
), expensive as (
    select 
        b,
        array_agg(a) as arr_a,
        ARRAY_TO_STRING(arr_a, '_') as c
    from tbl
    group by b
)
select
    x.a, 
    x.b, 
    y.c
from tbl as x
left join expensive as y 
on x.b = y.b;
```

the `expensive` cte could be in lined:

```
), expensive as (
    select 
        b,
        ARRAY_TO_STRING(array_agg(a), '_') as c
    from tbl
    group by b
)
```

I would suggest this is the best way. It does two things, the expensive aggregate function is only carrying/processing the data it needs, then this is used as a look-up on the "full table". This really is faster than trying to loop over all the rows in the raw sense.

As to using the Window Function form, it will call you function F for every row, because the ARRAY is created for every row, thus given the function sounds un-memoized (and perhaps not able to be), then a "cached version" is a JOIN. So given less than FOR EVERY ROW is a JOIN, do the JOIN known you are "caching". The thing to MAKE SURE you do, is use a EQUI-JOIN friendly type, which mostly means a NUMBER.